# Tensorflow: Fine tune Inception model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

For a few days I am following the instructions here:https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception
for fine-tuning inception model. The problem is that my dataset is huge so converting it to TFRecords format would fill my entire hard-disk space. Is there a way of fine-tuning without using this format? Thanks!

Comment: I found that the only I thing I need is images and labels that I can take them without TFRecords format, but I don't have powerful GPU to run the code so I don't know if that's right. Every opinion will be appreciated.

Comment: hey @chrisrn the github link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Fine-tuning is independent of the data format; you're fine there.  TFRecords promotes training and scoring speed; it shouldn't affect the quantity of iterations or epochs needed, nor the ultimate classification accuracy.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see the results running my code in powerful GPU.

Comment: I can't understand how the batch is changing in every iteration during training. The only I thing I get is that distortions are implemented on a single batch. Can you help? Thank you.

Comment: The data ingestion routines change batches (chooses different input files) every iteration.  This is part of what a framework does for you.  You have some control over the rotation: either in the original order of specification, or shuffled.  Regardless, each image gets included once per epoch.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yeah but I can't understand exactly  the batch changing. I see that in file image_processing.py there is random shuffling. Is it implemented from batchnorm_updates? Anyway, I am not working with TFR so I defined images and labels as placeholders and made a function for getting random batches in every iteration, so I think this technique is working.

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with TF internals, so I don't know the routine names.  I expect that the rotation is in the input flow, rather than where we update the batch normalization.  In any case, if the testing accuracy progresses nicely for you, then I expect that you're doing fine with the "original flavor" image set.  It's just going to be slower than the TFR version.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: In the image_processing.py script distortions are implemented to the image and in the documentation mentions nothing. Are distortions a step that surely must be done? The only I have done is rescaling values in [-1, 1]. I also asked in git but that's a stackoverflow question.

Comment: ... and should be a separate question, actually.  Please close out this question and post that independently, as other people will need the answer.

Comment: The short answer is "probably", depending on the distortions performed.  Some are to get a common image size or view; others are for extra accuracy in the final model.

Answer (score 1):

You can train any model without converting your data to tfrecords. [Here](https://gist.github.com/omoindrot/dedc857cdc0e680dfb1be99762990c9c) there is a great gist that fine-tunes VGG by reading directly from jpg files. You can change the slim architecture to the Inception one and you should be fine!

In the current configuration your dataset must be divided into train and test folders, with classes as sub-folders. But you can change it to whatever you want.

I've not experienced any huge difference in the speed of the code compared to the one that uses tfrecords.